# Create SQL login with sp_executesql proc

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

The following code is not working:

```
declare @pUserName nvarchar(50) = N'[test2]' ;
declare @pPassword nvarchar(50) = N'''123456''';

declare @QueryString as nvarchar(max);
declare @ParmDefinition as nvarchar(max);

SET @QueryString = N'CREATE LOGIN @dUserName WITH PASSWORD= @dpassword , DEFAULT_DATABASE=[Yerknain] ,DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english], CHECK_EXPIRATION=ON, CHECK_POLICY=ON';
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@dUserName nvarchar(50) , @dpassword nvarchar(50)';  

EXECUTE sp_executesql @QueryString, @ParmDefinition,
                             @dUserName =  @pUserName, 
                             @dpassword = @pPassword;
```

It's throwing an error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '@dUserName'.

but when I alter it to the following :

```
declare @pUserName nvarchar(50) = N'test2' ;
declare @pPassword nvarchar(50) = N'123456';

declare @QueryString as nvarchar(max);
declare @ParmDefinition as nvarchar(max);

SET @QueryString = N'CREATE LOGIN [@dUserName] WITH PASSWORD= ''@dpassword'' , DEFAULT_DATABASE=[Yerknain] ,DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english], CHECK_EXPIRATION=ON, CHECK_POLICY=ON';
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@dUserName nvarchar(50) , @dpassword nvarchar(50)';  

EXECUTE sp_executesql @QueryString, @ParmDefinition, 
                            @dUserName =  @pUserName, 
                            @dpassword = @pPassword;
```

it is working, but instead of registering the new user with name "test2", it is registering it with name "@pUserName".

is there any way to solve this problem with `sp_executesql` procedure (not just by exec , I need to check everything) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it with string concatenation like this for building the `@QueryString`. Note that when doing it this way, you don't need to send these as parameters to `sp_executesql`.

```
SET @QueryString = N'CREATE LOGIN '+QUOTENAME(@dUserName)+' WITH PASSWORD= '''+REPLACE(@dpassword,'''','''''')+''' , DEFAULT_DATABASE=[Yerknain] ,DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english], CHECK_EXPIRATION=ON, CHECK_POLICY=ON';
```

Comment: but in this way the parameters will be not checked whether they are at exact length or type , it will just put it there without checking yes ? so there is the risk of SQL injection ? or it's ok from security side ?

Comment: @AlphasSupremum **(1)** By placing the user name between rectangular brackets, and replacing any instances of single-quote (`'`) by two single-quotes (`''`) in the password, you are protected from SQL injection attacks. **(2)** You cannot create a login name using a parameter, that is why my answer concatenates the user name in the string. However I am not sure if the password can be passed as a parameter, you should try and see if that works. In any case, what I wrote is safe versus SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: @AlphasSupremum I've revised my answer to use the [`QUOTENAME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/ms176114.aspx) function, which is a better guard against SQL Injection in this case. It is generally not a good idea to quote yourself by putting rectangular around names. The `QUOTENAME` function will always do it best.